# Update images in documentation automatically

Tags: images, automation, documentation-generator

I'm looking for a tool/software to keep software documentation for a website project always up-to-date.

Especially the images in the documentation, e.g. explaining user masks etc. gets out of sync and someone (at the lower end of the payrange) needs to update those images according to the newest UI.

Is there a way to automate the extraction of certain website parts (maybe based on html tags/Ids e.g. of a div with id="user-create-modal") and to embed an image accordingly named "user-create-modal.png" into our online documentation with a link to that ever-updated url?

Comment: It heavily depends on the website design (especially parallax scrolling) and the size of the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

If the images that you need to reference are also always on-line the easiest is to actually link to them where they live, *(with the owners permission of course),* then when they are loaded as a part of your documentation they will always be current.

Alternatively, you can easily use [python](https://www.python.org/):

- the [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/) library to fetch the images,
- then [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/) to resize/convert/etc. the image(s) if required - even annotate them.

The python script could be run on a regular basis and check if the image(s) have changed and if they have either upload the revised images automatically or, *better*, prompt for a review - if the images at the other location have been changed inappropriately you do **not** wish to be uploading them to your online documentation.

Of course if the required images are things like screenshots of your own application then you can simply use [pyAutoGUI](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), *or similar*, to control your application so as the navigate to the appropriate point(s) then populate any fields take the required screenshots for inclusion in your documentation.

Comment: If I unserstand the OP correctly, they are not asking about images that already exist, but about generating new screencaps of an application's current user interface.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Updated to take this possibility into account.